# How can I make bootstrap sub-menus align with parent menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found this JQuery code here on SO. It works nicely, except my sub-menus open at the bottom of the parent menus instead of aligning themselves to the right. With this code,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('extra-nav-class').find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
    }, function() {
        var na = $(this)
        na.find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(800).slideUp('fast', function(){ na.removeClass('extra-nav-class') })
    });

    $('.dropdown-submenu').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('extra-nav-class').find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
    }, function() {
        var na = $(this)
        na.find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(800).slideUp('fast', function(){ na.removeClass('extra-nav-class') })
    });

})
```

can it be augmented to make the sub-menus roll out to the right of the parent menu instead of the the parent bottom?

Comment: Show your HTML and CSS also. If possible it would be good if you could post an image and show.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I'll close this post now. In all my trying to get this to work, I'd commented out the CSS and forgot abt it. It works as it shld. Too much eggnog last night :D

Comment: Ha ha... Merry Christmas.

Comment: Same to you and yours.